# Invoking a mule non-webservice flow from Activiti

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio, activiti, bpmn

I have a JMS mule flow, which will read messages from a queue and process them. I would like to invoke this flow from a process in Activiti. I am using a remote mule instance. From what I understand, to invoke a mule flow in a remote mule instance, I have to use web service. How can I use web service in this case?

I am using the community edition of mule.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the Web Service URL for your remote Mule instance, you would need to do one of two things:

1. Create a serviceDelegate class that calls the Web Service endpoint and call this from Activiti
2. Use the Camel module with Activiti to handle the call to Mule

Personally I am a fan of using Camel for this sort of thing since the hard work has already been done for you and it is a relatively simple matter to create a camel route and call it from an Activiti service task (there are even BPMN extension attributes built into the latest versions of Activiti that make this even easier).

Other things to consider.
Is this a fire and forget (i.e. one way) call or are you expecting a response? If you are expecting a response, will it be synchronous or asynchronous? All these factors will impact how you model the BPMN flow to properly integrate the Mule flow.

Comment: Thanks Greg for the reply. Is all this possible in the Community edition? I have been trying out simple examples (in embedded mode) to connect to mule from Activiti, but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Also, how can I get the WebService URL for the remote mule instance. I am sorry if this is a dumb question. I am a beginner to both mule and activiti.

Comment: Always difficult when you have a number of new technologies to digest. You will need to expose your flow as a SOAP web service (I found the following simple tutorial on this : http://marcotello.com/mule-esb/simple-web-service-in-mule-esb-3-3/). Now you have the service to call, you use Apache Camel to make the SOAP call. Details of how to use Camel can be found here: (http://bpmn20inaction.blogspot.com/2013/03/using-camel-routes-in-activiti-made.html). The Camel enhancements for 5.12 version of Activiti were contributed by one of our consultants at BP3 so perhaps we are a little biased. :-)

Comment: Thank you Greg ! I'll try this out.